# Unity IOC was last updated in Oct'15. Have they stopped further development?

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, unity-container, autofac

I am currently in process of selecting an IoC for my .NET application. I have researched about nInject, Unity, and Autofac. As Unity being a Microsoft thing, I had a first preference, but it seems the package's current version was released during Oct'15, and there are no further releases after that.

Whereas, NInject and Autofac are good alternates of Unity, and they were last updated in April 2017 only.

Could any one please suggest Unity is still a good choice for the new project considering its not updated since a while? Or should we look at the alternates like, NInject, Autofac, or StructureMap?

Any suggestions on this will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend (for a new project) to use an IOC container that is still maintained, so that you will get bugfixes, improvements, documentation, etc....

The Unity-container does its job and is a good component (I have always used it in my previous projects), even the further development of the component has paused (The project seems dead). But it is unlikely that you will get any updates (fixes, new features, improvements) of the component in the near future unless you maintain it on you own.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. Yes, after referring to various documents/ blogs about Unity and decommission of its support, I agree for a new project, we should look for a different IoC (may be, AutoFac, NInject, etc) instead of Unity